# delete user comment but keep it - count

Tags: mysql

When an user deletes a post or a comment I just set is as 1 on `delete` column.

The problem is, I use a count to show user how many comments he has on the post.

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, count(DISTINCT comentarios.id) as comentarios_count from posts p 
join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id
where p.delete='0' and comentarios.delete='0'
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

the problem is comentarios.delete='0' will select only posts that has at least one comment. I want to select all posts, but only count the comments that `delete` is set to 0.
what is wrong?

Comment: you're only selecting items where `delete='0'` so it's only counting them.

Comment: @Clint I want to count the comments from one post that delete is 0 and show all posts, even the ones that has no comment... my select is only get the posts that has at least one comment... don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Clint: yes that's what he wrote XD 
.... Rick: actually just select all and subtract the sum of delete ... dirty but should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about selecting all and just subtracting the deletes

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, count(DISTINCT comentarios.id) -sum(comentarios.delete) as comentarios_count from posts p 
join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id
where p.delete='0' 
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

Comment: oh, it works! like magic... -sum(comentarios.delete) get only the ones set as 1?

Comment: it just summs up .. so if you set one item to 2 or more the numbers will not be right anymore .. as i said . it's dirty ...

Comment: an alternative solution can be using count(DISTINCT if(comentarios.delete<>'1',comentarios.id,null)) this will keep the distinct part

Comment: amazing! each one is faster? do you thing I can have any impacts in my website spead using this?

Comment: in any case leveraging on any index here is improbable ...
if you intend to pull large quantities from that database  all of the above wouldnt be very fast. 
sometimes it can help to prepare temporary tables in memory leveraging indexes

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional sum instead of count, like this :

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user,
SUM(CASE comentarios.Deleted WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
as comentarios_count from posts p 
join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id
where p.delete='0' 
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

It will count the comments have not deleted and seems faster than calculating COUNT and SUM for each post

Comment: it works very well too! and really seems faster! thank you friend!